# Form tag bug with Chrome only

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, position

My page is working perfectly with IE 7 8 9, Firefox, Safari and Opera.
But when I open it with Chrome, the `DIV` with the `form` are not always well positioned.
If I delete the form tag, the problem disappear.
I don't have float, only absolute on this part of the code. Apparently the problem comes from the `form`, and only whith Chrome.

The CSS code :

```
#fond-diapo{background:url('../images/pattern2.gif');height:420px}
    #diapo-center{width:920px;margin:0 auto 0}
    /* Contactez nous */
    #contact-home{position:absolute;margin-left:600px;width:258px;height:421px;background:url('../images/contactez-nous-fond.png') no-repeat;}
    #contact-home h3{color:#c37ed5;padding:100px 0 0 75px}
    .form2{margin:26px 0 0 34px;height:406px}

    #contact-home p{width:192px;padding:8px 0 0 0}
    #contact-home  input[type=text]{padding:0 6px 0 12px;width:192px;height:29px;background:url('../images/fond-input.png') no-repeat;color:white}
    #contact-home select {border:1px solid #c6c4c4;color:#4f4f4f;float:right;width:150px}
    #contact-home  input[type=submit]{background:none;color:white;margin:18px 0 0 48px;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:2px;font-size:18px;cursor:pointer}
    .gecko #contact-home  input[type=submit]{margin:15px 0 0 48px}
    .ie7 #contact-home  input[type=submit]{margin:10px 0 0 0}
    .ie7  #contact-home select{margin-top:-18px}
    .bordertop{width:192px;height:1px;border-top:1px solid #c6c4c4;margin:10px 0 0px 0}
    .ie7  #contact-home  input[type=text]{padding-top:6px}
    .ie8  #contact-home  input[type=text]{padding-top:6px}
    .ie7 .bordertop{margin:4px 0 0px 0}
    .ie8 .bordertop{margin:4px 0 0px 0}
```

The HTML code :

```
<div id="fond-diapo">
            <div id="diapo-center">

                <div class="absolute">
                    <img src="images/carrousel/img1.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div id="contact-home">
                     <h3>01 75 57 85 45</h3>
                        <form action="#" name="form2" class="form2">
                         <p>Remplissez le formulaire, nous vous rappelons sous 24 heures.</p>
                         <p><input type="text" value="Votre nom et votre pr&eacute;nom" onFocus="javascript:this.value=''" /></p>
                         <div class="bordertop"></div>
                         <p><input type="text" value="Votre n° de t&eacute;l&eacute;phone" onFocus="javascript:this.value=''" /></p>
                         <div class="bordertop"></div>
                         <p><input type="text" value="Votre adresse Mail" onFocus="javascript:this.value=''" /></p>
                         <div class="bordertop"></div>
                         <p>
                            Lieu :
                            <select name="fonction">
                            <option value="paris13">SWF paris 13eme</option>
                            <option value="paris16">SWF paris 16eme</option>
                            </select>
                         </p>
                         <input type="submit" value="VALIDER" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Fin du div contact-home -->
            </div>
            <!-- Fin du div diapo center -->
        </div>
        <!-- Fin du div fond diapo -->
```

Comment: do you have a live example of your website somewhere? if so, please  provide us with a link :)

Comment: This appears to be working fine for me in Chrome 22, but I am not including `<div id="fond-diapo">`, as it does not have a closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your two stylesheets are loading alongside the css_browser_selector.js

Sometimes the css is first, sometimes the JS is between the two css.

This would account for different display issues on subsequent loads.

Try putting your css at the top, and your js and the bottom of the page.

Or, wait to fire the JS until the page is loaded.

Comment: Hi and thanks, i tried to add this to my CSS but the problem still there.

Comment: I had put it dont now why doesnt appear, here it is : http://jsforweb.com/startway/

Comment: Yes this is the problem, sometimes yes sometimes not, if i could send you a picture it ll be more efficient.

Comment: Really odd -- only get the display problem on every other load.  sometimes it displays fine.

Comment: Yes, i now make me crazy. Because it more simple when it work or not.

Comment: so far, my guess is the css_browser_selector.js, and the order in which the page is loaded.  Make sure that all elements are loaded before applying the javascript to it.

Comment: Yes it works !! Thanks you very much Circusdei, great to always find answer, like if there is always great people to help. I just call the JS after the CSS and the problem resolved.

Comment: Glad i could help.  Firebug is your friend ;)

Comment: Yes i ll use it more; how do you do to help other ? You go and find an answer ? Or you have to be admin or something ?